# How do you use string.erase and string.find?

Tags: c++, string

Why cant i call string.find in string.erase like so: `str.erase(str.find(a[1]),str.size())`?
edit:code added

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// html tags
string tags[5]={"<!--...-->","<!DOCTYPE>","<a>","<abbr>","<acronym>"};
//

//check if string exists
int boolStringExists(string a, string b)
{
    if(a.find(b)>0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(a.find(b)<=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
//erase tag from string a
void eraseTags(string a,string b[])
{

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        int x=(boolStringExists(a,b[i]));
        while (x>0)
        {
            a.erase(a.find(b[i]),b[i].size());
            x=(boolStringExists(a,b[i]));
        }
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    fstream file;
    file.open("h:\\a.htm");
    string k,m;



    while(getline(file, k))
        m += k ;


    eraseTags(m,tags);


    return 0;
}
```

Gives this message: "this application has requested  the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.Please contact the application's  support team for more information."

Comment: Why do you think that this does not work? If you have an error, please post it, along with the relevant code. Ideally this is a minimal code example that compiles, runs and reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that call (assuming `a[1]` exists and is found in `str` at least once)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
        std::string str = "Hello, world!";
        std::string a = "wwwwww";
        str.erase(str.find(a[1]), str.size());
        std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

test run: https://ideone.com/8wibR

EDIT: Your full source code fails to check if `b[1]` is actually found in `str`. The function `boolStringExists()` returns `1` if `a.find(b)` is greater than zero, and the value of `std::string::npos` which it returns when `b` is not found in `a` IS greater than zero.

To fix this while keeping the rest of your logic intact, change that function to

```
//check if string exists
bool boolStringExists(string a, string b)
{
    return a.find(b) != string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the string is not found, `find` returns `string::npos`, and then your code wouldn't work and will give runtime error. See this gives error : https://ideone.com/NEhqn

So better write this:

```
size_t pos = str.find(a[1]);
if ( pos != std::string::npos)
   str.erase(pos); //str.size() is not needed!
```

Now this doesn't give error : https://ideone.com/IF2Hy

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to erase everything that comes after str.find(a[1]). In that case you can omit the second argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        std::string str = "Hello, world!";
        std::string needle = "o,";
        str.erase(str.find(needle));
        std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

In this example I used `needle` instead of `a[1]`, but the principle is the same.